# algorithm/data structure for this "enumerating all possibilities" task (combinatorial objects)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

This is probably a common question that arises in search/store situations and there is a standard answer. I'm trying to do this from intuition and am somewhat out of my comfort zone.

I'm attempting to generate all of a certain kind of combinatorial object. Each object of size n can be generated from an object of size n-1, usually in multiple ways. From the single object of size 2, my search generates 6 objects of size 3, about 140 objects of size 4, and about 29,000 objects of size 5. As I generate the objects, I store them in a globally declared array. Before storing each object, I have to check all the previous ones stored for that size, to make sure I didn't generate it already from an earlier (n-1)-object. I currently do this in a naive way, which is just that I go through all the objects currently sitting in the array and compare them to the one currently being generated. Only if it's different from every single one there do I add it to the array and increment the number of objects currently in there. The new object is just added as the most recent object in the array, it is not sorted, and so this is obviously inefficient, and I can't hope to generate the objects of size 6 in this way.

(To give an idea of the problem of the growth of the array: the first couple of 4-objects, from among the 140 or so, give rise to over 2000 new 5-objects in a fraction of a second. By the time I've gotten to the last few 4-objects, with over 25,000 5-objects already stored, each 4-object generates only a handful of previously unseen 5-objects, but takes several seconds for the process for each 4-object. There is very little correlation between the order I generate new objects in, and their eventual position as a consequence of the comparison function I'm using.)

Obviously if I had a sorted array of objects, it would be much more efficient to find out whether I'm looking at a new object: using a binary midpoint search strategy I'd only have to look at roughly log_2(n) of the n objects currently stored, instead of all n of them. But placing the newly generated object at the right place in an array means moving half of the existing ones, on average, to make room for it. (I would implement this with an array of pointers pointing to the unsorted array of object structs, so that I only had to move pointers instead of moving data, but it still seems like a lot of pointers to have to repoint at each insert.)

The other option would be to place the objects in a linked list, as insertion is very cheap in that situation. But then I wouldn't have random access to the elements in the linked list--you can only find the right place to insert the newly generated object (if it's actually new) by traversing the list node by node and comparing. On average you'd have to traverse half the list before finding the right insertion point, which doesn't sound any better than repointing half the pointers.

Is there a third choice I'm missing? I could accomplish this very easily if I had both random access to stored elements so I could find the insertion point quickly (in log_2(n) steps), *and* I could insert new objects very cheaply, like in a linked list. Am I dreaming?

To summarise: I need to be able to determine whether an object is new or duplicates an existing one, and I need to be able to insert an object at the right place. I don't ever need to delete an object. Thank you.

Comment: Hash table? Not enough specifics here to tell if that could work (also, there may be an enumeration strategy that doesn't produce duplicates in the first place.)

Comment: Christophe - the code for generating the objects is over 1500 lines of C. That's why I've given a prose description of the task. David - thanks for the suggestion, I will experiment with constructing a hashing function. The data is structured essentially as an array of small ints, in such a way that a lexicographical comparison works. Do you have any suggestions fo where to read about hashing functions? I've only ever thought of them as involved in cryptography. And yes an enumeration strategy that avoids redundant generation would be terrific but I haven't been able to think of one. Thanks.

Comment: Re hash functions: http://blog.reverberate.org/2012/01/state-of-hash-functions-2012.html . I have some expertise on combinatorial enumeration, but it's difficult to advise you with no understanding of the problem on my end.

Comment: Sounds like a [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) to me. But if you're really "enumerating all possibilities", then you shouldn't require a method to check for duplicates, instead you need a method that generates permutations without duplicates.

Comment: David E: Thanks, I may come back later and ask you for your advice on this enumeration - I looked at some of your projects, very impressive. This is a recreational problem for me, whose only goal (beyond perhaps a new sequence for the OEIS) is the pleasure of pure problem solving. I work full-time in an unrelated field, I squeeze this hobby into spare moments here and there, and I'd rather ask the minimal advice necessary to move me to the next step in my own plodding time. My follow-up question about hashing comes in the next comment...

Comment: So if I understand correctly how hashing would help me, I use a function that will take object A (we can think of it as an array of ints) as an input, and quickly turn it into a single hash value, i. (Final step in this computation will probably be a remainder operation modulo p=some large prime.) I maintain a hash table of size p, where I place a pointer to object A at the table index i. Later on, when I generate array B, I compute its hash value and I go and see if there's an entry in my hash table at that index; if there is, I follow the pointer and make sure it's really the same object.

Comment: [ran out of space in the last comment] - is that the right idea? And I know I have to pick a strategy for dealing with hash collisions.

Comment: With a good hash function, you can use any size table you like; powers of two are a common choice because the modulo operation can be done with a (cheap!) bitwise AND. There are plenty of C hash table implementations out there, but if you want to do your own, I would suggest that you consult a data structures text.